# Adding HTML attributes dynamically with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to add a HTML attribute to a form field to disable it if a property is true in a JSON file.

On my form field I have added `data-is-disabled={{field.rules.disabled}}` which is read in from the following from the JSON

```
"rules" : {
    "disabled": "true"
}
```

I then have a directive in my module where I am wanting to remove that attribute and replace it with a `disabled` attribute to disable the field.

```
app.directive ('isDisabled', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (element) {
            element.removeAttr("data-is-disabled");
            element.attr("disabled");
            var fn = $compile(element);
            return function(scope){
                fn(scope);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

It seems overly complicated, however it is necessary for multiple different field type situations, in this case the field needs to be disabled.

I have tried a few different solutions from around SO, but I haven't got it working yet. The attribute remains as `data-is-disabled="true"`.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it simpler and use this.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

`ng-disabled={{field.rules.disabled}}`

Be careful and check your data because true is a string, instead do...

`ng-disabled={{JSON.parse(field.rules.disabled)}}`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was actually as simple as that! Thank you for such a quick and accurate answer!

Comment: No problem, I ran into the same problem several months ago.

Answer (score 1):

use this link property:

```
directive ('isDisabled', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : {
          isDisabled : "="
        },
        link : function(scope, ele, attr){
          if(scope.isDisabled){
            ele.attr("disabled", true);
          }
        }
}
```

see link : https://plnkr.co/edit/01JnAyDEce2p43aHlL83?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much @sandeep